# Question on talmud bavli succah 33B

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim, masechet-sukkah

Rav Chisda says that Rebbi says only black and red berries invalidate the hadas but green berries won’t since it’s specie from the hadas. Why does he only exclude black berries and not say to exclude all colored berries Besides green since only green is kosher because it’s Specie of hadas.

> Rav Ḥisda said: This statement was stated by our great rabbi, Rav, and may the Omnipresent come to his assistance: The Sages taught this halakha only with regard to ripe, black berries, since they stand in stark contrast to the green leaves of the branch, which then appears speckled. However, if its berries are green, they are considered of the same type as the myrtle branch, as they are the same color. Consequently, the branch does not appear speckled, and therefore it is fit. - [Sukka 33b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.33b.2?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Comment: I don't know but just for discussion: The berries start off green and go through red to black. So you can't empirically say that red berries are *passul* because there is a colour gradation from green through to red and at some stage they will be kosher (mostly green) and at some stage *passul* (mostly red).

Comment: "Rav chisda says that Rebbi says only black and red berries invalidate the hadas" That is not the tradition that R. Hisda reported in the name of Rebbi, here is the quote:  אמר רב חסדא דבר זה רבינו הגדול אמרו והמקום יהיה בעזרו ל"ש אלא ענביו שחורות אבל ענביו ירוקות מיני דהדס הוא וכשר
You are conflating R. Hisda's tradition from Rebbi with R. Papa's qualification: אמר רב פפא אדומות כשחורות דמיין

Comment: Ya but I have the same question. Why at the conclusion of the gemera does it only say black and red berries if in fact all berries besides green would invalidate it!

Comment: are the berries of that species ever a color other than red black and yellow?

Comment: Ya there are also other colors